# How can I hide the window when I run a exe

Tags: c++, winapi, pipe

I have this

```
static std::string exec(char* cmd) {
            FILE* pipe = _popen(cmd, "r");
            if (!pipe) return "ERROR -22";
            char buffer[128];
            std::string result = "";
            while(!feof(pipe)) {
                if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
                        result += buffer;
            }
            _pclose(pipe);
            return result;
```

}

But the problem i have is that i want to hide the program that lunches how can I do that? thx

Comment: You can't use _popen(), you must call CreateProcess yourself so you can specify the CREATE_NO_WINDOW option.  Follow the link in the MSDN _popen article to the boilerplate sample code.

Comment: Also note you don't want `while (!feof(pipe)`, you want `while (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe)) result+=buffer;`

Comment: @HansPassant i have to do it like this so i can get the out put of the
console programs then is there some other way to do this.

Comment: You didn't look at the link.  Look at the link.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hans Passant mentioned in the comments, you have to use [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to spawn the child process instead of `_popen`, since `_popen` does not give you any control over the window creation process.

To hide the console window, use the [`CREATE_NO_WINDOW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) process creation flag for the `dwCreationFlags` parameter.

In order to capture the output of the process, you need to create a pipe for its standard output stream with [`CreatePipe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Assign that pipe handle to the `hStdOutput` member of the `STARTUPINFO` structure you pass in, and make sure to set the `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` flag in the startup info's `dwFlags` so it knows that that member is valid.  Then, to read data, you just use [`ReadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the pipe handle.

Hans also provided a link to a good example of creating pipes with a child process [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499.aspx), although that example is doing more than you need to do—it's creating pipes for all three streams (stdin, stdout, and stderr), whereas you only need to capture stdout.

Comment: I gave you all the tools you need.  You just need to [snap the blocks together](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/08/04/9856634.aspx).